# Testing with TransactionTestCase uses real database

Tags: python, django

When I test using *django.test.TransactionTestCase* I have found that it uses the real database.

(*django.test.TestCase* works normally!)

I have confirmed this in my own project using the simple code:

```
class TestInventoryTransactions(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print(Item.objects.all())

    def test1(self):
        pass

    def test2(self):
        pass
```

The output of this is

```
[...Bunch of items...]
[]
```

Showing that firstly that the real database is being used and not an empty test database.
Secondly, it removes *everything* from the database after the first test.

I really don't think this is the expected behaviour and don't see why it would be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *"manage.py test"* does not have this problem. It only occurs when running the test file manually.